# ajax + php + json = login

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I've made a login that uses ajax to send the form to a php file which should return the result..however in a couple of browsers I get errors, while in firefox it seems to work like a charm.
JS:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://www.xxxxxx.net/login.php",
        data: dataString,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(json) {
            if(json.jresult==false){
                alert(json.jerror);
            }
            else{
                if(json.identification==0 || json.identification==1){
                    // register: do some stuff
                }
                else if(json.identification==2){
                    //  login: do some stuff
                }
                else{
                    return(false);
                }
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('error:'+errorThrown+',status:'+textStatus+',xhr:'+xhr);
        },
        complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert(textStatus);
        }
    });
```

Errors I get from the ajax call using Safari,Opera and Rockmelt:

**@complete function:** textStatus=error
**@error function:** error:,status:error,xhr: [Object object]

PHP:

```
session_cache_limiter('nocache');
header('Expires: '.gmdate('r',0));
header('Content-type: application/json');
// set response array
$aDataR = array();
$aDataR['jresult'] = false;
$aDataR['identification'] = -1;
if(!isset($_POST['iID'])){
}
else{
    if($_POST['iID']==0){
        /* REGISTER */
    }
    elseif($_POST['iID']==1){
        /* LOST PASS */
    }
    elseif($_POST['iID']==2){
        /* LOGIN */
        $aDataR['identification'] = 2;
        if(false==($mResponse = $cChallenges->CheckLogin($_POST['sUser'],$_POST['sPass']))){
            $aDataR['jerror'] = "No such user/password combination";
            $cChallenges->ProbeLogin($_POST['sUser'],$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
        }
        else{
            $aDataR['jresult'] = true;
            $aDataR['jsuccess'] = "Thanks for logging in";
        }
    }
}
echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($aDataR), ENT_NOQUOTES);
```

Left out all code that wasn't important.
Hope anyone can help me out on this one, thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the actual result of your ajax call? Look at it in your debugger console. What's xhr.responseText?

Comment: That sounds like a PHP error, json_encode should always print a string. Try to debug your PHP application.

Comment: I do get results, if I json_encode the output and mail it to me:    array (
 'jresult' => true,
 'identification' => 2,
 'jsuccess' => 'Thanks for logging in',
 'user' => 'zomgwtfbbq',
 'points' => 3315,
 'ranking' => 1,
 'posts' => 10,
)

Comment: I'm sorry this is the json, posted the var_export of the array: {"jresult":true,"identification":2,"jsuccess":"Thanks for logging in","user":"zomgwtfbbq","points":3315,"ranking":1,"posts":10}

Comment: Do you got this JSON per mail, or in Firefox? Why don't you get it in the other browsers?

Comment: I get that response in chrome and firefox (and if mail it the same too of course)..updated both jquery and the browsers that give the issues but still the same. Any other options that I have? Been messing with this for over a week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably this is encoding issue. try this

```
echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($aDataR), ENT_QUOTES);
```

Answer (score 0):

let me see if i understand this correctly, the ajax data comes back correctly formatted ONLY in chrome & firefox, and even then, ONLY if you email the json to yourself? Please, clarify.

Comment: oops, i meant this to be a comment, still, glad to help if we can  reach some sort of clarity